# Do all ciphers have equivalent decryption keys?

Tags: keys, known-plaintext-attack

Do all ciphers suffer from the problem of multiple equivalent decryption keys? Is the existence of equivalent keys an essential property for the security of a cipher?

If you could prove that a cipher had no equivalent keys, would that lead to a procedure for recovering the key under the known-plaintext attack model?

Comment: Are you talking about symmetric key ciphers?  Because most modern block ciphers are designed to have no weak keys, which includes equivalent keys (like the weak and semi-weak keys of DES).  What lead you to believe that equivalent keys would be essential for security?

Comment: A linear system has a unique solution if it is non-singular and requires no guesswork. But it seems guessing is a desirable feature of a cipher solution.

Comment: A block cipher is ideally very far from a linear system.  Large classes of equivalent keys greatly weaken the cipher, because a key-guessing attacker only has to test one key per equivalence class.

Comment: What is an equivalent decryption key?

Comment: @AndrewHoffman it's two (or more) keys that all work to decrypt a ciphertext correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do all ciphers suffer from the problem of multiple equivalent decryption keys?

No. The number of non-equivalent keys is bounded by the number of permutations. Since the number of permutations is *very* high there is a very big chance that ciphers do not have equivalent keys. This is especially true for ciphers with a high block size (AES with 128 bits). Even if an equivalent key would exist, it would probably be rather tricky to find a set of two equivalent keys. How tricky depends on the cipher of course.

> Is the existence of equivalent keys an essential property for the security of a cipher?

Therefore no.

> If you could prove that a cipher had no equivalent keys, would that lead to a procedure for recovering the key under the known-plaintext attack model?

No. Finding that a cipher does not have equivalent keys would enhance the security of the cipher, not decrease it.

More information about equivalent keys [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3805/encryption-scheme-with-equivalent-keys).

Comment: Efficiently proving the absence of equivalent keys for typical block ciphers sounds pretty difficult. It seems possible that if your cryptoanalysis is successful enough for such a proof it'll also be successful in breaking the cipher.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Depends a bit on the key schedule I suppose. It could be that the key schedule is not that strong while the rest of the cipher is. That would probably exclude the cipher from being used in the construction of a hash function, but it may not break the cipher (thinking out loud here).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, this was part of the question, I was wondering if it would lead to an attack.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I can prove that one time pad does not have equivalent keys.

Comment: @Joshua A one-time-pad is hardly a "typical block cipher".

Comment: Just _how many more_ permutations than keys there are is worth emphasizing. 2^128 factorial [is a number with more than 2^128 _bits_ in it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(log2((2%5E128)!))). If ciphers approximate random permutations like they should, ciphertexts under any two keys shouldn't match for more than a few plaintexts.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Nor is a Turing Machine a common computation device. Yet a TMis often used to construct proofs. Here, the proof is that there exists at least one cipher with non-equivalent keys, namely the One Time Pad. Now it might be interesting to refine the proof, e.g. _are there ciphers with equivalent decryption keys, whose key length is fixed and shorter than the maximum message length?_, But that's another matter. In this case, the second halt of the question (attack vectors based on unique keys) can also be answered using the OTP cipher: No, you can't attack an OTP like that.